# Thales HSM LMK keypairs: 00-01, 02-03, 08-09, 10-11, 12-13

Tags: hsm

In the Thales HSM documentation, 40 LMK keypairs are listed but the following keypairs are not shown in the keytype table:

- 00-01
- 02-03
- 08-09
- 10-11
- 12-13

Am I correct in thinking that the keypairs above are only used internally by the HSM?

Comment: I would suggest you fire this question towards the Thales support team via the contact details at http://www.thales-esecurity.com/support-landing-page.